# Error 419 Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy usando el form del Register.blade del auth de Laravel para ingresar valores en 2 tablas distintas, la tabla User del auth de Laravel y otra tabla llamada personas asociada al modelo Persona En el RegisterController tengo este código en la función create.

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{

    $datos= ['nombre' => $data['name'],'apellido' => $data['surname'],'cedula' => $data['cedula'],'email' => $data['email'],
    'telefono' =>$data['telefono'],'direccion' =>$data['direccion'],'ciudadResi' =>$data['ciudadResi'],'genero' =>$data['genero'],]; 
    var_dump($datos);

    Persona::create($datos)([
        'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
        'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
        'email' => $datos['email'],
        'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
        'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
        'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
        'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
        'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
        'estado'=> '1',
        'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
    ]);
    
    User::create($data)([
        'name' => 'clienteUser',
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'nick' => $data['nick'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => 'cliente'
    ]);
    
}
```

Pero cuando trato de ingresar valores me dá el error 419, buscando en internet vi que este error por lo general se dá porque falta  @csrf en el form pero en el Register.Blade en el form si está, pongo el código también.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="surname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Surname') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="surname" type="text" class="form-control @error('surname') is-invalid @enderror" name="surname" value="{{ old('surname') }}" required autocomplete="surname" autofocus>

                            @error('surname')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nick" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nick') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="nick" type="text" class="form-control @error('nick') is-invalid @enderror" name="nick" value="{{ old('nick') }}" required autocomplete="nick" autofocus>

                            @error('nick')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="cedula" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cedula') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="cedula" value="{{ old('cedula') }}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>

                            @error('cedula')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Teléfono') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control @error('telefono') is-invalid @enderror" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" required autocomplete="telefono" autofocus>

                            @error('telefono')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="direccion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Direccion') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="direccion" type="text" class="form-control @error('direccion') is-invalid @enderror" name="direccion" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" required autocomplete="direccion" autofocus>

                            @error('direccion')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="ciudadResi" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Ciudad de Residencia') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="ciudadResi" type="text" class="form-control @error('ciudadResi') is-invalid @enderror" name="ciudadResi" value="{{ old('coudadResi') }}" required autocomplete="ciudadResi" autofocus>

                            @error('telefono')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="genero" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Genero') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="genero" type="text" class="form-control @error('genero') is-invalid @enderror" name="genero" value="{{ old('genero') }}" required autocomplete="genero" autofocus>

                            @error('genero')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Register') }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como se puede ver si está el @csrf y no se que otra cosa podría dar el error debido a que soy nuevo en Laravel.
Si necesitan alguna otra parte del código o que explique algo más con gusto lo puedo hacer. Los valores quemados solo son para probar por ahora.

Comment: Debiera ser `Modelo::create([...datos...])`. Tú estás haciendo, en buenas cuentas, `Modelo::create([...datos...])([...datos...])`

Comment: @ffflabs no entiendo bien lo que me quieres decir, ¿me podrías explicar un poco mejor? Por modelo me imagino que te refieres al de Persona::create($datos) pero no veo donde le vuelvo a poner paréntesis.

Comment: tienes  `Persona::create($datos)([ más datos])` y  `User::create($data)([ otros datos]). `.

Comment: es que cuando hago el registro genero un usuario y también una persona o esa es la idea, pero Persona no usa todos los datos del form y User tampoco, por eso cojo algunos valores de $data y los guardo en $datos para guardarlos en persona y para user nomas uso los datos que quiero en $data. Quiero ingresar lo del modelo Persona en una tabla persona y lo de User en la tabla Users @ffflabs

Comment: Eso lo entiendo pero, por favor, quita el `($datos)` después de `Persona::create`  y el `($data)` después de `User::create`. Asegúrate de dejar sólo `Persona::create(['nombre' => $datos['nombre'], etc etc ])` y  `User::create(['name'=>'clienteUser', etc etc ])`.

Comment: entonces me dices que deje como Persona::create([
            'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
            'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
            'cedula' => $datos['cedula'],
            'email' => $datos['email'],
            'telefono' =>$datos['telefono'],
            'direccion' =>$datos['direccion'],
            'ciudadResi' =>$datos['ciudadResi'],
            'fechaNacimiento' =>'1998-03-05',
            'genero' =>$datos['genero'],
            'estado'=> '1',
            'idTipoPersona'=>'2'
        ]);   @ffflabs

Comment: Ahora por lo que veo el 419 era un problema de cache, pero veo que lo que ahora no me deja es insertar los valores quemados, fechaNacimiento, etc.  Voy a ver si hago otra pregunta con esa duda, si pudieras revisarla te agradecería @ffflabs.